# How to create phonetic input method with Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode, input-languages

I am trying to create a phonetic keyboard layout for Bangla

But the problem is, I can't assign a combination of keystrokes to input a single unicode character

For example:

I can assign key "M" to unicode character "ম"

But I can't assign "OI" to unicode character "ৈ"

The expected result would be "মৈ" which indeed sounds like "moy"

Is there any way I can achieve such results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) for this. In it, using 'hotkey', you can map a character to combination of characters (or performing a task). To map a combination of characters to a combination of characters, you can use 'hotstring'.

Here is the online documentation: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm